# How to correctly access TextInput values and assign them to state variables?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I keep getting this error

```
Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.
```

the code still seems to work even when this error is thrown. It happens when I use setState with textInput components for example -

```
 return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
            <Text>Title of project:</Text>
            <TextInput
              editable={true}
              placeholder="Type here"
              value={this.state.title}
              style={styles.textInput}
              onChangeText={this.handleTitle}
            ></TextInput>
```

and

```
class CreateProject extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { title: "", dueDate: "", visibility: false };
    this.handleTitle = this.handleTitle.bind(this);
  }

  handleTitle = (text) => {
    this.setState({ title: text });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

don't bind your function in constructor if you are using arrow functions.

```
class CreateProject extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { title: "", dueDate: "", visibility: false };
  
  }

  handleTitle = (text) => {
    this.setState({ title: text });
  };
```

or you can use inline function

```
  <TextInput
              editable={true}
              placeholder="Type here"
              value={this.state.title}
              style={styles.textInput}
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({title: text})}
            ></TextInput>
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot when I open the project back up, will let you know thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You code seems to work, see [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@keyserve/crabby-soda)

Comment: Yeah, my code seems to do what I want it to do, but it still throws a non-critical error so I'm worried I'm doing something that is bad practice, I guess its not an urgent issue I need to resolve. Thanks :)